# Access is denied on User Profile - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt, user-profiles

My system has four disks in it

- C: 120GB (SSD) for system
- D: 1TB
- E: 500GB
- F: 2TB

My user is `mark` and my profile is here `D:\Users\mark`

All disks are encrypted with truecrypt whole disk encryption. D,E,F are system favorite volumes and are mounted with the system at boot time.

The D drive filled up, so I emptied the F drive and copied my data over logged on as a different user called admin with this command

`robocopy D:\Users\mark F:\Users\mark /MIR /XJ`

Seemed to work well. I then went into the registry and changed the User profile location at this key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\{SID}` and changed `ProfileImagePath` to `F:\Users\mark`

I also changed:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\ProfilesDirectory` to `F:\Users`

When I log on to Windows I get a load of errors. In the event log I can see

`Windows cannot load the user's profile but has logged you on with the default profile for the system. DETAIL - Access is denied.`

When I look at the drives, they have all been mounted fine by Truecrypt. I tried changing the registry keys back to how they were but I get the same error. I have also tried a System Restore but it did not fix it.

Any ideas? I'm kind of in trouble here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

[user Profile Fixing Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215)

Comment: Method 1 fixed it, my profile registry key had a .bak on the key name and I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have done something that might no be reversible.

Microsoft says user profiles are not movable:

> By changing the default location of the user profile directories or
>   program data folders to a volume other than the System volume, you
>   will not be able to service your Windows installation. Any updates,
>   fixes, or service packs will fail to be applied to the installation.
>   Microsoft does not recommend that you change the location of the user
>   profile directories or program data folders. [emphasis added]

Now there are tools that allow you to do just that:

> The tweak involves using Microsoft's enterprise deployment tools,
>   including Sysprep, to install Windows. An answer file (in XML format)
>   specifies a custom location for the Users folder.

The best thing to do would be to restore from your backup but otherwise you may try to follow the exact steps [outlined for Sysprep here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7files/thread/565f16a5-e5ed-43c9-8422-4f56aebb296e)

[More info here](http://www.zdnet.com/dont-move-your-windows-user-profiles-folder-to-another-drive-7000022142/)

Comment: Thanks, but I have moved my stuff using this method from the C to the D drive for a good few months now with no issues at all. Not sure why it's gone bad now. The sysprep option looks involved, might give that a try.